# Get a reference to the instantiated object within its own class method?

Tags: methods, coffeescript, instance

I'm trying to return the instantiated object from its own method described in a class, but the only thing I get is the reference to the class, not the instance

```
class A 
  a: ()->
    console.log(@)
    b=()-> console.log(@)
    b()
  c: ()=>
  console.log(@)

yoyo = new A
yoyo.a()
yoyo.c()
```

And it returns:

```
A {c: function, a: function}
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
A {c: function, a: function}
```

But what i'd want it the yoyo object to be returned, how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your version doesn't work because `b` is just a plain old function and `@` (AKA `this`) generally depends on how a function is called: if you call a function as a function then `@` will usually be `window`.

There are lots of ways around this:

1. The old `self = this` trick works in CoffeeScript too:

   ```
   self = @
   b = -> console.log(self)
   b()
   ```

   This requires you to talk about `self` instead of `@` though. This approach doesn't seem to be as common as it used to be.
2. You can create a bound function using the native [`Function.protype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function:

   ```
   b = (-> console.log(@)).bind(@)
   b()
   ```

   `Function.prototype.bind` gives you another function that always has the desired `@`.
3. You can create a bound function using CoffeeScript's [fat arrow (`=>`)](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) instead of the usual skinny arrow (`->`):

   ```
   b = => console.log(@)
   b()
   ```

   This has the same effect as using `Function.prototype.bind`. This is probably the most common way to do this sort of thing in CoffeeScript.
4. Specify the desired `@` when you call the function by using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

   ```
   b = -> console.log(@)
   b.call(@) # or b.apply(@)
   ```

Which approach you use depends on your specific situation.

Comment: All of your solutions still returns the A object, and not yoyo, the desired instance, or I may have missed something

Comment: Did you replace the `b` inside your `a` function with the any of the above? They all do what you seem to be asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gqznhzxk/

Answer (score 0):

I think this example could say your gotchas

```
class A
  a: false
  b: -> alert @.a

yoyo = new A
yoyo.a = true
yoyo.b()
```

If `@` is `class A` not yoyo instance variable, then yoyo.b will tell you always false. but you try this via [link](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20A%0A%20%20a%3A%20false%0A%20%20b%3A%20-%3E%20alert%20%40.a%0A%0Ayoyo%20%3D%20new%20A%0Ayoyo.a%20%3D%20true%0Ayoyo.b())